# Is it acceptable to use the imperfect preterite tense instead of the conditional in the written language?

Tags: tempo-verbal

In ptBR we frequently use the imperfect preterite instead of the conditional in the spoken language. I've also seen it in writing in sentences like:

- "Se você me convidasse **eu ia**." (ao invés de "eu iria")
- "Eu **não ia** dizer uma coisa dessas." (ao invés de "eu não iria")
- "Eu **podia** falar com ela a respeito disso." (ao invés de "eu poderia")

**Is this substitution acceptable in the written language?**

EM PORTUGUÊS -  É aceitável a troca do futuro do pretérito pelo pretérito Imperfeito do indicativo  na língua escrita? Na língua falada, no Brazil, ouvimos mais frequentemente o segundo onde o primeiro deveria ser usado. Ou estaria eu errado e ambos seriam corretos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trocar o futuro do pretérito pelo imperfeito, o futuro simples pelo presente (ou por *ir + infinitivo*), são muito comuns -- aliás, a regra -- no registo oral. Podemos ir mais longe e substituir ainda o subjuntivo pelo indicativo. Por exemplo, a frase:

> Se ele tivesse apanhado a bola, teria marcado golo.

pode ser reformulado em linguagem popular por:

> Se ele tem apanhado a bola, marcava golo.

Em geral, a linguagem popular prefere a certeza do indicativo (em lugar do subjuntivo) e do presente/imperfeito em detrimento do futuro/futuro do pretérito.

Em registos mais formais, no entanto, estas substituições são incomuns. Por exemplo, o futuro simples raramente é usado na linguagem oral (onde quando muito é usado para expressar dúvida como em "será que", sendo substitído pelo presente, *ir + infinitivo* ou *haver de + infinitivo*), mas [é a forma mais comum na linguagem escrita](http://www.filologia.org.br/xiiicnlf/XIII_CNLF_04/tomo_2/futuro_simples_x_ir_infinitivo_uma_analise_diacronia_do_uso_CHRISTIANE.pdf) (apesar de *ir + infinitivo* ter ganhado algum terreno ultimamente e ser usado uma vez por cada três do futuro simples). [Estoutro artigo](http://www.abralin.org/site/data/uploads/revistas/2008-vol-7-n-2/04-josane-moreira-e-silvia-rita1.pdf), que analisa textos escritos ao longo de vários séculos, calcula a distribuição de presente/ir + infinitivo/haver de + infinitivo/futuro simples para indicar um evento futuro em 7% / 15% / 2% / **76%**, no século XX no Brasil.

Não tenhos dados para a distribuição de imperfeito/futuro do pretérito, mas a minha sensibilidade é que o futuro do pretérito é muito mais comum na linguagem escrita (quando são substituíveis).

Em suma, não se trata tanto de uma questão de correção, mas de escolher as formas mais apropriadas para o registo em causa. A forma mais apropriada para a linguagem escrita é o futuro do pretérito.

Comment: Em ptBR diríamos, popularmente, "se ele pega a bola, marcava o gol."  Vide a música "Ah se eu te pego..."

Comment: Apesar de no Brasil ser comum, em Portugal no registo escrito o condicional ainda é usado amiúde, e mesmo no registo oral, em meios eruditos, como na Política ou na Justiça, o condicional é a regra.

Answer (score 4):

Pode fazer uso dessa forma verbal em registo oral, todavia no registo escrito, deve evitá-lo, para mais se o registo for erudito:

> Se me convidasse, eu iria.

Com o conjuntivo

> Se me tivesse convidado, eu teria ido.

Todavia pessoalmente, tento sempre usar a forma verbal do condicional mesmo no registo oral. É para isso que ele serve e permite formas claras mais curtas sem menção à palavra que estabelece a condição (se, caso, etc.).

> Convidar-te-ia sempre!

Repare na distinção

> Marcaria sempre o golo! (sob qualquer condição em qualquer altura)
>
> Marcava sempre o golo! (no passado, marcou sempre os golos)