# O uso, pelos portugueses, do pretérito imperfeito do indicativo no lugar do futuro do pretérito

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, português-europeu, conjugações

De um tempo pra cá comecei a perceber que os portugueses têm esse costume. Em frases onde no português brasileiro se esperaria o futuro do pretérito (-ia), em pt-PT é usado o pretérito imperfeito do indicativo (-ava).

Exemplos que encontrei na internet:

> Eu até deixava aqui o meu site de memes originais, para quem está a dizer que gosta dos memes em Brasileiro, mas depois eles estragavam o 9GAG. [< Fonte >](https://www.facebook.com/mynameisnurb/posts/253047908092513?comment_id=2633814&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D)

Pode-se perceber que o tempo da frase está no presente, e a pessoa está falando de possibilidades, condições, mas o pretérito imperfeito é usado, como se fosse costume "estragar" o 9GAG, mas depois passou a não ser mais. Em pt-BR seria algo assim:

> Eu até deixa**ria**<sup>1</sup> aqui o meu site de memes originais, para quem está dizendo que gosta dos memes em português brasileiro, mas depois eles estraga**riam** o 9GAG.

<sup>1</sup> Ou "deixava" mesmo, nesse caso também é usado assim em pt-BR, mas não no caso de "estragavam".

Outro exemplo:

> Gostava de saber quando se usa o «ao qual» e «à qual». [< Fonte >](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-de-o-que-ao-qual-e-a-qual/30323)

Costumava gostar, mas agora passou a não gostar mais. XD

Apesar de no português brasileiro também ser usado o pretérito imperfeito do indicativo em frases como "Até deixava você ir, mas apenas se voltasse", "Eu podia falar isso, mas não vale a pena" ou "Nooossa, não deixava!", porém em pt-PT o pretérito imperfeito do indicativo é usado em situações diferentes, situações essas em que seria usado o futuro do pretérito no brasileiro.

Por que isso? Existe o futuro do pretérito no português europeu? Depende da região? É assim mesmo que é dito em pt-PT?

Comment: Vê [Is it acceptable to use the imperfect preterite tense instead of the conditional in the written language?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/is-it-acceptable-to-use-the-imperfect-preterite-tense-instead-of-the-conditional) É capaz de ser duplicata, não? Curiosamente na pergunta apresenta-se «Se você me convidasse **eu ia**» como exemplo de ptBR; esta frase é típica do ptPT informal, mas eu pensava que em ptBR fosse sempre ***eu iria***.

Comment: @Jacinto Quase. A pergunta sugerida se refere aos momentos em que pode-se usar tanto o futuro do pretérito quanto pretérito imperfeito do indicativo. Porém minha pergunta se refere a momentos em que é usado pelos portugueses o pretérito imperfeito do indicativo quando tal não é usado no mesmo caso em pt-BR, como "Gostava de saber", etc.

Comment: Relacionada: [É correto dizer “eu farei” e/ou “eu vou fazer”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/269/%C3%89-correto-dizer-eu-farei-e-ou-eu-vou-fazer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Todos os casos que indicaste são típicos do português europeu informal. Em nenhum deles o pretérito imperfeito estabelece qualquer tipo de relação com um tempo de referência passado — tem antes um valor modal.

Primeiro, o uso do pretérito imperfeito do indicativo pelo condicional (futuro do pretérito) em orações condicionais ou equivalentes. Na primeira frase há um antecedente implícito:

> Eu até deixava aqui o meu site de memes originais (...), mas, **se o fizesse**,  eles depois *estragavam* o 9GAG.

Sobre este assunto, diz a *Gramática do Português* editada pela Gulbenkian, na pág. 520 (numa secção escrita por Fátima Oliveira):

> Em construções condicionais, o pretérito imperfeito pode **(em português europeu)** [negrito meu] ser usado na oração consequente em vez do condicional como se ilustra em:
>
> (20) a. Se a Maria tivesse lido o jornal [já ***sabia***/*saberia*] as notícias].
>          b. [A Maria ***tomava**/tomaria* esse remédio] se o médico lho recomendasse.
>
> Nestes dois casos, obtém-se uma interpretação epistémica (ou seja, de possibilidade) de toda a frase; em particular (20b) [...] tem uma leitura contrafactual [...].
>
> Do mesmo modo, em construções paratáticas como [as seguintes], o imperfeito também pode ser usado, a par do condicional, com uma interpretação contrafactual [...]:
>
> (21) a. Ele bebeu durante toda a noite. Mais um copo e ***ultrapassava**/ultrapassaria* os limites de álcool no sangue (cf. *se tivesse bebido mais um copo, ultrapassava/ultrapassaria os limites de álcool no sangue*)
>         b. Os bombeiros chegaram no momento exato. Mais um minuto e a criança ***afogava-se**/afogar-se-ia*. [...]
>
> Compare-se (21b) com *os bombeiros acorreram ao local, mas [um minuto depois a criança **afogava-se**]*. [Onde a expressão de localização temporal anafórica permite uma leitura temporal de Passado do imperfeito]

Repare-se que mesmo a frase (20b) pode ser interpretada contrafactualmente.

Existem contudo outros casos menos acentuadamente modais em que o pretérito imperfeito pode substituir o futuro do pretérito. Fátima Oliveira (nas [*Actas do 2.º Encontro Nacional da Associação Portuguesa de Linguística*](http://www.apl.org.pt/docs/actas-02-encontro-apl-1986.pdf), 1986) dá o seguinte exemplo (pág. 88):

> Ele soube que eu não vinha no dia seguinte.

Mas partindo das condicionais, encontramos frases em que poderá estar oculta uma condicional (por exemplo «se não te importasses») e o imperfeito «serve para ativar uma hipótese, ou sugestão, a decidir e por isso pode ganhar a força ilocutória de proposta, pedido, anúncio de intenção, etc., consoante as condições do contexto e da situação» (Oliveira , 89). Alguns exemplos de Oliveira e da *Gramática do Português*:

> 1. Espera um pouco. *Ia* só ali buscar um livro.
> 2. Sendo assim, fazia o almoço num instante e depois saíamos.
> 3. Agora, *bebíamos* um cafezinho, não?
> 4. Se chegarmos a horas ao Porto, ainda *íamos* a tua casa.
> 5. Amanhã *passava* pelo seu gabinete.
> 6. Vocês *podiam* contar agora coisas da vossa viagem.

Daqui partimos para os casos de “delicadeza”, casos nos quais se insere a tua segunda frase. Oliveira dá os exemplos:

> *Vinha* agradecer-lhe [...] [citando a gramática de Cunha e Cintra]
>   *Fazia* a fineza de… ?
>   *Davas*-me a direção do Pedro?

Aqui não está em causa qualquer oração condicional. O futuro do pretérito poderia ser usado com valor modal semelhante nas duas últimas frases, algo que é mais comum no Brasil, a julgar por este artigo de *Marine* e *Barbosa* intitulado [*Gostava que fizessem este exercício. – Gostava ou gostaria?*.](http://www.gel.org.br/estudoslinguisticos/volumes/37/EL_V37N1_19.pdf) Oliveira diz que este uso é uma estratégia para «evitar uma afirmação peremptória de intensão ou de autoridade e em exprimir a deferência que merece o enunciatório» (pág 90).

Também temos usos em que o imperfeito marca um contraste. Dados estes exemplos:

> - A - O que estás aqui a fazer?
>     B - *Estava* à espera do jornal.
> - Já não te via há muito tempo.
> - Fazia-te em Évora.

A interpretação destas frases assinala a existência de dois intervalos exclusivos — aquele indicado pelo imperfeito e um outro imediatamente anterior ao momento da enunciação, na transição dos quais se operou uma mudança de estado. No caso da última frase, a transição faz-se entre aquilo que o enunciador acreditava ser o mundo real e o mundo real (Oliveira, p. 83). Este efeito de contraste (a que não é alheio o facto de o imperfeito ser usado em condicionais contrafactuais) é também conseguido através da criação de um mundo irreal que contrasta com um mundo real em frases como (Oliveira, 84):

> *Pensava* que eras médica.
>   *Querias*!…

Voltando à frase inicial:

> Eu até *deixava* aqui o meu site de memes originais, para quem está a dizer que gosta dos memes em Brasileiro, mas depois eles estragavam o 9GAG.

O primeiro *deixava* já não nos deverá surpreender. Existe em certa medida uma condicional implícita (*se eles não fossem depois estragar o 9GAG, eu deixaria aqui o meu site de memes originais*), que é expressa com recurso a um mundo irreal em que o enunciador anunciaria o seu site de memes originais, construído pelo imperfeito.

---

Estes usos modais do imperfeito hão de ocorrer com menor frequência no Brasil, mas não tenho muitos dados a esse respeito. A gramática de Evanildo Bechara (gramático brasileiro), em todo o caso, menciona alguns (pág. 345 da versão eletrónica da 37ª ed.):

> Nos pedidos e solicitações [o pretérito imperfeito] ou denota que duvidamos da realização do fato ou exprime um desejo feito com modéstia ou com o simples
>   propósito:
>
> > “Queria viver para o seu filho – é como ele explicava o desejo da
> >     vida”.
> >     Sr. Manuel, eu *desejava* telefonar.
>
> Pode substituir, principalmente na conversação, o futuro do
>   pretérito, quando se quer exprimir fato categórico ou a segurança do
>   falante:
>
> > “Se me desprezasses, morreria, *matava*-me”

Answer (score 3):

**Refiro-me a língua falada, em pt-BR.**

**"eu até deixava"** é comum em **pt-BR**. Não posso afimar se mais comum do que "eu até deixaria", mas é bem comum na língua falada.

- "Olha, se eu fosse você **eu deixava tudo de lado** e ia embora".  Neste caso em particular creio ser o imperfeito mais comum do que o condicional ("eu deixaria") em pt-BR.

Já com o verbo gostar, concordo que **"eu gostava de saber"** é menos comum que **"eu gostaria de saber"** mas ainda assim ouve-se ocasionalmente entre os mais letrados.  Por outro lado, dizemos "eu ia gostar de saber" com mais frequência do que "eu gostaria de saber" **quando não estamos em busca de uma informação**.  Notem bem, "eu gostaria de saber" é muito usado quando queremos uma informação:

- "Eu gostaria de saber se você não vai fazer o que prometeu"

Mas não no seguinte contexto:

- "Ah, eu ia gostar muito de saber que eles se separaram."

Há essa diferença entre **"eu gostaria de saber"** e **"eu ia gostar de saber"** conforme demonstram os exemplos acima. Em "gostaria", tu buscas uma informação.

E ainda, **"eu queria saber"** (imperfeito do indicativo) é mais comum do que **"eu quereria saber"** (condicional).

Quanto a **"depois eles estragariam"**, não é a forma mais comum em pt-BR.  Dizemos mais frequentemente **"depois ele iam estragar"**  e neste caso, "iam", da mesma forma que "estragavam", está no imperfeito do indicativo

Creio que a diferença transatlântica está mais na língua falada onde em pt-BR usa-se o condicional um pouco mais frequentemente, embora não haja nenhuma regra a respeito.

Quanto à pergunta **"existe o condicional em pt-PT?**  Sim, ele existe.  No registro oral e da nesma forma que em pt-BR, contudo, **frequentemente usa-se o imperfeito do indicativo em seu lugar**.  Em pt-BR eu diria "Se ele me dissesse uma coisa dessas...ah, eu dava um soco na cara dele", mas eu não diria  "eu daria um soco na cara dele".

Comment: "*Quanto a "depois eles estragariam", não é a forma mais comum em pt-BR.*"  "Eles iam estragar" é bastante informal, mas "Eles estragariam" é igualmente comum, eu mesmo diria "estragariam" se fosse eu. E "eu queria saber" não tem o mesmo sentido que "eu quereria saber" ou "eu iria/ia querer saber".

Comment: @BrunoLopes     No registro oral eu nunca ouvi "eu quereria saber".  Independente do contexto, soa pedante.

Comment: Nem eu, ouve-se sempre a segunda (ia/iria querer), mas é possível. Exemplo: "-- Se você fosse ele, qual seria sua reação? -- Eu quereria [iria/ia querer] saber o que aconteceu!"

Comment: Francamente, eu acho que "Ah, eu ia gostar muito de saber que eles se separaram." tem um **sentido condicional:gostaria**, apesar de ser imperfeito. Talvez estes usos pertencem a um registro meio baixinho tambem...

Comment: @Lambie  Eu vejo uma diferença entre o meu exemplo  "Ah, eu ia gostar muito de saber **que** eles se separaram.", e  "Ah, eu ia gostar muito de saber **se** eles se separaram."  A primeira frase refere-se a sentir alegria com a confirmação da separação.  Já na segunda frase, a pessoa quer apenas dizer que apreciaria a informação, seja ela "sim" ou "não".

Comment: Essa diferença entre *ia estragar" (imperfeito) e "estragaria" (condicional) não existe em termos de sentido na linguagem falada.  O problema do **que** e **se** é outro. É óbvio que "se eles se separam" e "que eles se separam" têm sentidos diferentes.

Comment: Em Portugal, "[...] depois eles iam estragar [...]" também soa lindamente" (e "estragariam" também seria formal); tu não chegas a dizê-lo, mas portanto concordas com o Yuuza que não se ouve muito no Brasil "[...] depois eles estragavam [...]"?

Comment: @Jacinto    Sim, não se ouve muito.  A não ser em "nós fazíamos tudo com tanto capricho, mas depois eles estragavam tudo".   Mas aí já é o imperfeito do indicativo em seu uso rotineiro.

Comment: E isso é por ser o verbo *estragar* ou é por ser a consequência que, logicamente, ocorre mais tarde? Por exemplo, já podia ser *estragava* em "ah, eu também estragava (estragaria) este, só que depois não me davam (dariam) outro"?

Comment: @Jacinto  1. Se eu desse um desses pra ela, ela ia estragar logo-logo.  (mais freqente)  2. Se eu desse um desses pra ela, ela estragava logo-logo.   (menos frequente).  3. Se eu desse um desses pra ela, ela estragaria logo-logo (**acho** que é a forma menos frequente das três, na língua falada.  Mas ouço as três formas nesse contexto.

Answer (score 1):

No português br também se usa a locução `ia +verbo` no português falado muito mais comumente que propriamente o futuro do pretérito  `-ria-`. No entanto com mesmo valor semântico.

> -Eu ia falar, mas não deu tempo.
>   Se pegasse um táxi, ela ia chegar mais cedo.

Ou a locução `iria+verbo`.

> Eu iria comer do bolo, mas precisei sair antes.

Comment: Olá Rebeca, bem vinda ao Portuguese SE! Me permita sugerir destacar as frases de exemplo com aspas, "como essa", ou com o sinal `> ` seguido de espaço (como editei tua resposta - você pode alterar minha edição, se desejar) ao invés de escrevê-las em maiúsculas: pois essas são de desagradável leitura e podem ser interpretadas como texto gritado. Também é recomendável evitar abreviações como "tbm" e, em geral, ser cuidadosa na redação. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

No Brasil, o fenômeno é em geral restrito à segunda e terceira conjugações:

> Eu queria saber como é que chegaste a essa conclusão. (em vez de "quereria")

Mas

> Eu gostaria de saber como é que chegaste a essa conclusão.

(Em Portugal é comum dizer "eu gostava de saber", mas não aqui.)

Minha impressão é que as formas do futuro do pretérito e do pretérito imperfeito (que não deixa, afinal, de ser uma espécie de "presente do pretérito"...) são muito semelhantes na segunda e terceira conjugações (queria/quereria, comia/comeria, partia/partiria, ia/iria, etc.), o que faz mais natural a substituição (especialmente quando o verbo já tem um "r" na raiz, como "querer"). E que em Portugal - mas não no Brasil - depois se operou uma regularização lógica (se se faz assim na segunda e terceira conjugações, então se faz também na primeira).

Answer (score 0):

**PRETÉRITO IMPERFEITO EM PERÍFRASE (IA + V [infinitivo])**, o caso discutido aqui:

> 2. Outra forma que substitui o futuro do pretérito é formada pelo verbo IR (auxiliar) no imperfeito, seguido do infinitivo do verbo principal:
>      “Ninguém ia descobrir, ninguém ia vê-la.” (Verissimo, 1996)

Ou seja, usando o futuro do pretérito, a frase acima daria:
*Ninguém descobriria, ninguém a veria*. [padrão formal, mudança de registro]

[futuro do pretérito](https://www.laits.utexas.edu/clicabrasil/sites/laits.utexas.edu.clicabrasil/files/FUTURO%20DO%20PRETERITO.pdf)

Ou seja: O verbo IR é usado no imperfeito + um infinitivo para substituir o futuro do pretérito.

Tesis:
[...]

> ao nos depararmos com a língua usada na comunicação do dia-a-dia,
>   percebemos certos usos de imperfeito sem que seu significado denote
>   ação habitual / não concluída ocorrida no tempo passado, ocupando o
>   ambiente sintático-semântico tradicionalmente definido para o uso do
>   futuro do pretérito, como ocorre no slogan de uma famosa marca de
>   lingerie: "**Se eu fosse você, só usava Valisere**", veiculado através
>   da imprensa falada e escrita.

(negritos e itálicos meus)

> **Já antigos estudiosos da língua portuguesa verificaram que o futuro do pretérito pode ser substituído pelo imperfeito do indicativo em
>   alguns contextos.** Said Ali (1969)1 faz tal constatação no português
>   do Brasil do inicio deste século. *Podemos ir ainda mais longe: Vaz
>   Leão ( 1961 ), ao coletar periodos hipotéticos em textos literários,
>   mostra que o imperfeito do indicativo aparece neste contexto desde a
>   época do português arcaico*.

[Nota-se: Isso tambén inclui o PRETÉRITO IMPERFEITO EM PERÍFRASE (IA + V [infinitivo])

O caso discutido em nossa pergunta aqui:

Se encontra na tesis:

[Português informal no Rio de Janeiro](http://A%20VARIA%C3%87%C3%83O%20ENTRE%20FORMAS%20DE%20FUTURO%20DO%20PRET%C3%89RITO%20E%20DE%20PRET%C3%89RITO%20IMPERFEITO%20NO%20PORTUGU%C3%8AS%20INFORMAL%20NO%20RIO%20DE%20JANEIRO)

- PRETÉRITO IMPERFEITO EM PERÍFRASE (IA + V [infinitivo])

> **Se eu fosse você, só ia usar Valisere.**

Por transformação baseada nessa regra, podemos escrever:

> **Se eu fosse você, só usaria Valisere.**

[O sentido não muda.]

Ou seja, a subsituição é IA + infinitivo para o futuro do pretérito. Isso sim.

Na frase da pergunta: *Eu até deixava aqui o meu site de memes originais*, não seria uma frase bem feita, nem em linguagem coloquial.

Seria: Eu até ia deixar [ou deixaria] site de memes originais* [etc].

O futuro do pretérito, seja o formal [deixaria] ou informal [ia deixar, linguagem falada] "pode ser substituído pelo imperfeito do indicativo em alguns contextos", mais não na frase da pergunta.

Por exemplo: *Eu até gostaria de viajar pelo mundo*. não é: *Eu até gostava de viajar pelo mundo.*

S**e fosse possível sistematicamente** a substituição do futuro do pretérito pelo imperfeito, a communicação da frase acima se tornaria impossível.

Comment: Estás enganada. A frase em questão — “Eu até **deixava** aqui o meu site […]” —  está perfeitamente correta. Tem o mesmo significado que “eu até **deixaria** aqui […]”, mas não que “eu até **ia deixar** aqui […]”; porque este *deixava/deixaria* tem valor modal e não temporal. Está tudo muito bem explicado na resposta do Artefacto. Aliás, a resposta do Centaurus mostra que esta frase é também perfeitamente aceitável no Brasil. E encontras exemplos deste tipo de uso do imperfeito em várias gramáticas.

Comment: Claro, em certos contextos (veja minha resposta acima) "o futuro do pretérito pode ser substituído pelo imperfeito do indicativo nas afirmações condicionadas: *se tivesse estudado, tinha um bom emprego*." Aqui, a frase não é condicionada. Estudo universitário: https://lume.ufrgs.br/bitstream/handle/10183/60707/000862149.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y

Comment: A frase está condicionada, sim senhor. A condição está implícita. Está tudo explicado na resposta do Artefacto. Poderias também dizer, naturalmente, "eu até deixaria aqui o meu site [...]", mas **não** podes dizer aquilo que tu sugeres, "eu até ia deixar aqui o meu site [...]", porque isto tem um significado diferente.

Comment: @Jacinto: Tudo bem. Se pensas que "Eu até deixava aqui o meu site de memes originais, para quem está a dizer que gosta dos memes em Brasileiro, mas depois eles estragavam o 9GAG." tem condição implícita, não tenho mais nada que dizer ao respeito. Não vejo leitura de uma afirmação condicionada possível. Eu acho que não disse que ia estragar e estragaria seriam 100% iguais em termos de sentido.

Comment: Tem, sim, condição implícita, tal como explicado na resposta do Artefacto. A frase é equivalente a "eu até deixava [= *deixaria*] aqui o meu site [...] **se** eles não fossem depois estragar o 9GAG". Não vejo nenhuma outra interpretação possível. Qual é a tua interpretação? Isto é uma tipo de frase comum em Portugal. Exemplo mais simples: "eu até comprava, mas não tenho dinheiro" = "eu até comprava se tivesse dinheiro".

Comment: @Jacinto Só em certos casos: Os estudos que vi citam um tal Cunha. "Em síntese, o pretérito imperfeito do indicativo é usado para: [...] (v) Substituir «pelo futuro do pretérito para denotar um facto que seria consequência certa e imediata de outro, **que não ocorreu, ou não poderia ocorrer**» (Cunha, 1991). O exemplo da pergunta é outra: ele deixava (imperfeito) e depois o pessoal estragava (também imperfeito). Ou seja, ele está falando (a falar, pt-ibérico) do que fazia e que não faz agora, no presente, hoje em dia.

Comment: E o seu exemplo mais simples ("eu até comprava, mas não tenho dinheiro" = "eu até comprava se tivesse dinheiro") deveria ser: Eu até **comprava se tivesse dinheiro** = Eu até **compraria se tivesse dinheiro**. E o comprar que muda de tempo, não o verbo ter.