# pretérito imperfeito vs futuro do pretérito

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, verbos, imperfeito-ou-perfeito

Olá,

Tenho uma dúvida sobre **pretérito imperfeito** e **futuro do pretérito**.

A dúvida é se posso usar os dois nos seguintes exemplos:

> Gostaria de ir com vocês, mas não posso.
>
> Gostava de ir com vocês, mas não posso.
>
> Minha filha queria ser médica.
>
> Minha filha quereria ser médica.
>
> Sem a sua ajuda, eu não podia acabar o trabalho.
>
> Sem a sua ajuda, eu não poderia acabar o trabalho.

Geralmente esses exemplos têm significados diferentes?

Comment: Em PT-BR é diferente, por exemplo. Gostaria de ir... significa uma vontade e não aconteceu. E Gostava de ir, significa que foi algo que aconteceu e não acontece mais. Mas em Portugal, vejo as pessoas usarem muito Gostava com o mesmo significado de Gostaria e não vejo usar Gostaria....
PS: Muito boa a pergunta, eu como nativo de PT-BR tenho essa mesma dúvida quando em PT-PT.

Comment: Uma referência: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/gostariagostava/296

Comment: Does this answer your question? [O uso, pelos portugueses, do pretérito imperfeito do indicativo no lugar do futuro do pretérito](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/o-uso-pelos-portugueses-do-pret%c3%a9rito-imperfeito-do-indicativo-no-lugar-do-futu)

Comment: Como a pergunta é restrita a [tag:português-brasileiro], não acho que seja um duplicado da [pergunta relacionada](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/o-uso-pelos-portugueses-do-pret%c3%a9rito-imperfeito-do-indicativo-no-lugar-do-futu) que o @Peixoto linkou - essa é sobre [tag:português-europeu].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, em geral, em pt-br, esses dois tempos verbais carregam significados distintos.

> 1. Gostaria de ir com vocês, mas não posso.
> 2. Gostava de ir com vocês, mas não posso.

(1) expressa uma possibilidade não realizada ou um desejo (aqui não realizado) - *I'd like to go with you, but I can't*.
(2) não se costuma usar em pt-br (**I used to like going with you, but I can't*).

> 1. Minha filha queria ser médica.
> 2. Minha filha quereria ser médica.

(1) expressa desejo, realizado ou não, presente ou não:

- "queria ser médica. E lutou muito para chega lá.";
- "queria ser médica. Mas ele nunca conseguiu passar no vestibular."
- "queria ser médica, depois se decidiu por psicologia."
- "queria ser médica, tomara que consiga." (aqui seria melhor "quer")

(2) eu diria que é um bocado incomum. Por vezes se poderia usar o composto:

- "Ela iria querer ser médica, se imaginasse ser possível."

> 1. Sem a sua ajuda, eu não podia acabar o trabalho.
> 2. Sem a sua ajuda, eu não poderia acabar o trabalho.

Ambos são similares, mas (2) indica provavelmente uma situação ainda mais distante de se realizar:

- "eu não poderia acabar o trabalho, por isso não aceitei o projeto."

Enquanto contextos para (1) poderiam incluir:

- "eu não podia acabar o trabalho, por isso tive que esperar por você."
- "eu não podia acabar o trabalho, por isso chamei a Maria."