# Quando e como se deve usar deviam / deveriam?

Tags: português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas, tempo-verbal

O @Math pediu-me ajuda no [StackOverflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) por causa [desta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/5422/revisions), onde o utilizador usa a 3ª pessoa do plural do pretérito imperfeito do verbo dever nesse texto a baixo. O @Math corrigiu para a 3ª pessoa do plural do condicional.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

O @Math corrigiu para

De referir que o utilizador é de Portugal e que o @Math que fez a edição é do Brasil.

A pergunta que fica é quando e como se deve usar deviam / deveriam? Neste caso qual está correta? Estão as duas?

Comment: @ Jorge B.                                                                                                                  The original question is here: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/is-it-acceptable-to-use-the-imperfect-preterite-tense-instead-of-the-conditional