# Problema de entender: "poderia" e "ia"

Tags: significado-em-contexto, tempo-verbal

Eu não consigo entender se é sobre algo que estava no passado e acabou. Ou se é sobre algo que é condicional.

Por exemplo:

> "Gostaria de estar com você."
>
> "Porque sei que você ia adorar."

Comment: Olá Daan, bem-vindo. :) Fiz umas edições à tua pergunta para a tentar melhorar. Se não estiveres satisfeito com as edições, edita de volta!

Comment: Não faz sentido mudar os exemplos da pergunta, quase 8 meses depois de eu ter escrito a minha resposta.  A minha resposta vai continuar a mesma e refere-se aos exemplos da tua pergunta inicial, formulada em setembro de 2018.  Porque mudar de "gostaria de estar com você" para "gostaria de nadar" ?  No meu entender isso não torna a pergunta mais clara ou mais fácil de ser respondida.

Comment: It's a good idea to use examples that are as simple as possible, but @Centaurus is correct, especially because it would require a not-so-simple change to the answer, as the 2nd example of the 5th version admits not only the translation "You would go to swim", but also "You intended to go to swim" and perhaps even "You used to go to swim".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«Gostaria» está no condicional, vê em https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/gostar
Essa frase traduz-se em inglês para:

> I would like to be with you.

«Ia» está no passado (pretérito imperfeito), vê em https://dicionario.priberam.org/Conjugar/ia
... mas tem o sentido de condicional.
Essa frase traduz-se em inglês para:

> Because I know that you would love it.

Nesta pergunta explica-se a troca do condicional pelo pretérito imperfeito, que acontece no teu caso do «ia»:

- [Is it acceptable to use the imperfect preterite tense instead of the conditional in the written language?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1207/is-it-acceptable-to-use-the-imperfect-preterite-tense-instead-of-the-conditional/2974)

Comment: Muito obrigado #ANeves.Eu intendo agora.

Answer (score 2):

This answer refers to the example sentences in the OP of September 2018, when it read: "gostaria de estar com você" and "porque sei que você ia adorar".

Depending on context, **"Gostaria de estar com você"** can be translated into two different sentences. When it's just an answer to "O que você gostaria de fazer amanhã?"

> - **"I'd like to be with you"**
> - **"I'd like to be by your side"**

Or, assuming either the speaker or the recipient is travelling and is far away, or that somehow it seems unlikely they can see each other, I would translate it as...

> - **"I wish you were here"**/**"I wish I were there"**
> - **"I wish I could be with you"** (now or tomorrow)

Then again, **"porque sei que você ia adorar"** seems to have only one time-related translation: the conditional. This time **the speaker uses "ia" (imperfect preterite) instead of the conditional (iria) as most Portuguese speakers do.**

> - **"Because I know you would love it"**