# Sequence of tenses in Portuguese

Tags: expressões, concordância-verbal, conjugações, concordância, modo-subjuntivo

In the following examples of using past conditional in Portuguese:

> Se tivesses embarcado com o Vasco da Gama para Índia, ías ver...

> Se eu soubesse que havia un temporal tinha atravessado a ponte mesmo a pé.

only one part of the conditional phrase uses mais-que-perfeito, whereas the other uses pretérito imperfeito. Assimil then notes that the seeming violation of the time agreement (see [sequence of tenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses)) is quite normal for Portuguese:

> Mais le portugais exige seulement que l'un des verbes marque le temps. (But the Portuguese requires only one of the verbs to show the tense.)

Is such liberty in using tenses a general feature of Portuguese or are there finer rules governing the use of tenses in complex sentences? Doesn't it introduce ambiguities when a (long) sentence starts in one tense, but then suddenly moves deeper into to the past? Are there examples of exploiting such confusions (e.g., in witticisms or idioms)?

Comment: Does [this](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1207/38) answer your question? Or [this](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3081/38)?

Comment: It's true that Portuguese is on the lax side with the usage of indicative/subjunctive and tenses. Your sentences are not really ambiguous, though. I don't see how they can be interpreted other than referring to some counterfactual in the past. If you wrote "se soubesse que havia um temporal, atravessava a pé", that can be interpreted in the same way ("nesse dia, se soubesse..."), or instead as referring to a factual pattern of behavior in the past though ("sempre que sabia que havia...")

Comment: @tchrist thank you for the links! This is indeed the kind of information that I was looking for.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145500/discussion-on-question-by-roger-vadim-sequence-of-tenses-in-portuguese); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é uma característica geral do português permitir que apenas um dos verbos da oração condicional marque o tempo verbal. Geralmente, é suficiente que o verbo principal indique o tempo em que a ação ocorreu, deixando o verbo auxiliar no tempo que melhor se adequa à intenção do falante.

No entanto, é importante ter em mente que essa liberdade no uso dos tempos verbais pode sim gerar ambiguidades e dificultar a compreensão da frase. Por isso, é necessário estar atento ao contexto e à intenção do falante para poder interpretar corretamente a oração.

Não tenho conhecimento de exemplos específicos de exploração dessas ambiguidades na forma de witticisms ou idioms em português, mas é possível que haja casos em que a intencionalidade do falante possa ser interpretada de maneira dupla ou até mesmo oposta, dependendo da escolha dos tempos verbais na frase.

Comment: Existe uma confusão aqui porque "conditional" e condicional. está bem confuso.  Ele fala past conditional quando se trata do mais que perfeito de um verbo composto.